# How to animate home button in action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I would like to animate the home button to tell the user to click on it. I want to use three different images to show the animation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the action bar in you `onCreate`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Create and load an animation drawable which [you defined in XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html):

```
// homeDrawable is a field on your activity
homeDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_thing);
```

Set the drawable as the icon on the action bar:

```
actionBar.setIcon(homeDrawable);
```

Post a `Runnable` to start the animation when the main thread is clear:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    homeDrawable.start();
  }
});
```

Don't forget to stop the animation at some point!