# Home icon on action bar animation with resize

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-animation

I want create home icon animation like in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ae.dubaiairports

I know how to add animation changing home icon eg

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:duration="3200" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon_second_state"
    android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

and I'm able to change icon size from code eg

```
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams iconLp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this.icon
            .getLayoutParams();
    iconLp.topMargin = iconLp.bottomMargin = 0;
    this.icon.setLayoutParams(iconLp);
```

now trying to combine those two or any other way to get this done. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289686/how-to-animate-home-button-in-action-bar

Comment: I have this part and it works. Now trying to add resize to this animation